# How to change the maven profile by being in a profile?

Tags: java, maven, jsf

I have a java application where I need to copy the data from one database to another. How can I copy data from dev db to prod db by using maven profiles.

My application has different profiles.
I want to make a dropdown which has all the profiles.
Whatever profile I select in the dropdown the data should go in that profile database.

[one of the profiles in my pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMO1j.png)

Comment: I already have a feature which copies in the same database. I will be using the same feature but how can I point to the other database by using maven profiles.

Comment: I think you mistake maven profiles for something different. Please elaborate on what exactly you want to do and how the Maven profiles should help you. Maven is a tool to help building applications.

Comment: We have a maven application website which includes jsf as the front end and hibernate spring in the backend. We connect to database by specifying the config.properties path in the different profiles like in my pom.xml I have:

Comment: It might be helpful if you post the relevant portions from the pom.xml in your question.

Comment: I have added the image in the question which has details for one of my profiles. Suppose I deployed my website with dev application and then from that website I want to copy the data of dev profile to prod profile.

Comment: In which build steps are these properties used and with which command the maven build is started?

Comment: We build using commands like this : mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Pprod. The command generates a war file which is then deployed on tomcat/jboss to run the web application. All the datbase activities use the profile values through which the war have been made. Do we have any option though which we can provide a target profile while copying the data to another database.

Comment: Unless your `prod` profiles activates the `ci` profile, the properties you posted in your screenshot are irrelevant, as that profile is not considered during the build. Check `mvn -Pprod help:active-profiles`. This should list all profiles that are active when executing your build like that.

Comment: We have many profiles, ci in the image which I have added is just an example. If we use ci we use this command: mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Pci .This command activates ci profile and when we deploy it, only ci database is active.